# Is Svelte on:transitionend also triggerd on MSTransitionEnd, webkitTransitionEnd & oTransitionEnd?

Tags: svelte

I am using Svelte,

I want to trigger an action upon transition completion,

I see this code with Jquery :

```
$("body").on(
"transitionend MSTransitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd",
function() {
    $(this).removeClass("start");
});
```

I use this inside Svelte :

```
on:transitionend="{stopAnim}"
```

Will this be the equivalent of the above ? Or will it miss the other cross-brower compatibility event types ?

Answer (score 1):

This will just add the `transitionend` event handler, but you [really should not need the others](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_transitionend_event).